# Add array for column value for duplicates [SQL]

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to add for duplicate values an array that contains all last_action values.
sample_table

```
client_id  action_timestamp  last_action
201        2020-01-01 09:00  click
201        2020-01-01 09:00  browse
303        2020-01-01 11:00  action
```

desired_output_table

```
client_id  action_timestamp  agg_action
201        2020-01-01 09:00  {click,browse}
303        2020-01-01 11:00  {action}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `array_agg`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (client_id,  action_timestamp,  last_action) AS (
    VALUES  ('201',        '2020-01-01 09:00',  'click'),
            ('201',        '2020-01-01 09:00',  'browse'),
            ('303',        '2020-01-01 11:00',  'action')
) 

--query
select client_id,
    action_timestamp,
    array_agg(last_action)
from dataset
group by client_id, action_timestamp
```

Output:

| client_id | action_timestamp | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 2020-01-01 09:00 | [click, browse] |
| 303 | 2020-01-01 11:00 | [action] |